# Where is the BOOL * argument to enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: created?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, objective-c-blocks

Recently at an interview I was asked when is the `BOOL *stop` value allocated and where is the memory held: in the heap or the stack?

Any ideas?

Comment: If by heap or stack, we mean dynamic or static memory? then it should be dynamic. Just a dynamic variable for the enumerator to know it should stop. I believe, its allocated in the function that calls the enumerations and should be released as soon as the enumeration is complete

Comment: the memory of `BOOL*` or the actual `BOOL` instance?

Comment: Probably BOOL and not the pointer.. but anyways both should be allocated at the same time isn't it ?

Comment: Strictly spoken the block does not *return a Boolean value*, it passes a **pointer** to a boolean value as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, u r correct :D